# Publishing builds to test environment

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Quick question: If I were to set up my build server to publish to a test environment after every check-in, wouldn't that constantly interrupt the testers if the ASP.Net site they are testing would come down periodically as developers check in their changes?

We are looking to ensure the bugs we have marked as resolved are always available for testing, but we also don't want our testers to have the site come down in the middle of their tests.

Thanks!

Chris

Comment: Try [InRelease](http://www.incyclesoftware.com/inrelease/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to have a dedicated environment for each tester (TFS Lab is a great way to achieve this).  Then allow each tester to manually kick off a build that updates their environment with the latest build whenever they desire.

If you must do a shared test environment, then I suggest not updating every build for specifically this reason, but instead doing a nightly build that updates it (and/or using a manual build that testers can run on demand).